# Ajax call to my Zend controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, zend-framework

I am bit new to zend framework. Trying to do an Ajax call to my controller/indexAction() and I am receiving error alert. 
Can someone please help? I tried to get answer from other posts, but could not able to get the correct solution.

My JS file with Ajax action.

```js
    $('.libox').click(function () {
        var contentPanelId = $(this).attr("id");
        alert(contentPanelId);
        $.ajax({
            url: "public_html/application/controllers/IndexController.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: contentPanelId,
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("fail :(");
            }
        });
    });
```

My Controller

```html
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action {

public function indexAction() {


    if ($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $_custObj = new Application_Model_DbTable_Shuffle();
            $this->_helper->json($_custObj->getData());
        }
    } else {
    }
}

}
```

Control is always going to error: function() shown in Ajax call and getting "fail:(" alert.

Comment: URL in ajax call is wrong. It should not end with extension.  You just need to mentioned controller name and action like '`url:"Index/index/" .

Comment: @SameerK - My index/Action is located in "public_html/application/controllers/IndexController.php" of my ZF. and I gave URL as "index/index". Still I am getting the same error.

Comment: controller name in URL needs start with capital letter , so its 'Index/index' . Apart from this couple of questions - 1) Where is JS file located??  2) have you configured controller path in application.ini file ?? 3) whether request to URL in resulting ``404 page not found`` error ??

Comment: Please find my response,
1) public/js
2)Yes
3) No, I am not getting this issue.

Comment: Can you share that configuration and as you making ajax request , initialize ``AjaxContext`` in your controller -> init function. If init() function not there then you can add.  ``public function init()
    {
     parent::init();
     $ajaxContext = $this->_helper->getHelper('AjaxContext');
 $ajaxContext->addActionContext('index', 'html')
      ->initContext()
    }`` .   If controller is returns json response , then replace ``html`` with ``json``

Comment: ead about zend routes to understand url routing

Comment: @SameerK - Thanks for your time. It worked after I changed URL as suggested by Aref Anafgeh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i changed your jquery code .use this:

```
 $('.libox').click(function () {
    var contentPanelId = $(this).attr("id");
    alert(contentPanelId);
    $.ajax({
        url: "/index/index",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: contentPanelId,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("fail :(");
        }
    });
});
```